# Safely removing test dependencies from an Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, automated-tests, package.json

I am building a small Angular 6 web app. It won't need any kind of automated testing or the like so I ran "ng new --skip-tests true MyProject".

I have looked through the project and it seems pretty clean. The only thing left that I had to remove was the e2e folder.

Now I am looking in the package.json. I am fairly certain there are a lot of packages I no longer need, but I am hesitant to delete them as I do not want to cause any problems.

Here is the package.json file generated by the cli.

```
 {
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I am fairly certain that I can remove all Jasmine and Karma dependencies. Also, it seems like I can remove the test script. Anyway, I figured I would double check on here before deleting anything. What testing dependencies can I safely remove from my package.json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One small piece of advice, no matter how small, you'll never know when you'll need tests and they don't really complicate the project that much. Leave them and they'll be there when you need it.

Anyway, I'd remove all karma, jasmine, and protractor packages; the test.ts file, and any section in angular.json defined for the test configuration. I suggest to leave lint, but you can also remove that.

Like with other things, remove small parts, compile, and test, and repeat until you have the barebones.

Comment: Noted on keeping the tests, that is a pretty good point, especially since they don't compile in the build. Anyway, I removed what you said and it worked great. Also removed the "test" and "e2e" scripts and the tsconfig.spec.ts file.